# How to stop handler or thread

Tags: java, android, mysql, database

My program is random string
First i press button for start and then it will random
Second i press same button again for it stop how can i do??

my code

```
package com.Randomsentence;
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Randomsentence extends Activity {
  protected static final int CONTINUE = 0;
  protected static final int STOP = 0;
  TextView txt;
  int time = 30;
  int random;
  public String[] myString;
  Button bt1;
  boolean check = false;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    bt1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt1);
    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        thread.start();
      }
    });
  }

  // our handler
  Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {//display each item in a single line
      {
        if (check == false) {
          Random rgenerator = new Random();
          Resources res = getResources();
          myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
          String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
          txt.setText(q);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        while(true) {
          sleep(1000);
          handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  };
}
```

this is XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
androidrientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_marginBottom="40px" android:layout_marginLeft="40px" android:layout_marginRight="40px" android:layout_marginTop="40px">
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:text="TextView"
android:id="@+id/txt" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginRight="40px"
android:layout_marginTop="50px"></TextView>
<Button android:text="Button" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/bt1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/txt" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txt" android:layout_marginLeft="40px"
android:layout_marginRight="40px" android:layout_marginTop="40px"></Button>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is array.xml insert in to folder values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="myArray">
<item>ข้าว</item>
<item>ข้าว</item>
<item>เส้นใหญ่</item>
<item>เส้นเล็ก</item>
<item>วุ้นเส้น</item>
<item>ข้าวผัด</item>
<item>เส้นใหญ่</item>
<item>ข้าว</item>
<item>มักกะโรนี</item>
<item>ผัดผัก</item>
<item>ต้มยำ</item>
<item>ทอดกระเทียม</item>
<item>ผัดพริกเผา</item>
<item>ผัดกระเพรา</item>
<item>ผัดน้ำมันหอย</item>
<item>ต้มยำแห้ง</item>
<item>ทอดกระเทียม</item>
<item>แพนง</item>
<item>ผัดกระเพรา</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: So much code ... are you sure all is needed. Please summarize your question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's not recommended to stop threads, let the OS do it for you. You should use a `flag` variable instead of `true` in your `while` loop and change it to `false` when you want to stop your thread. And about `Handlers` - they cannot be stopped, since they're simply designed to synchronize threads, so don't worry about them.

Comment: can you show the code. I am very new to android. So confuse very much

Comment: I want to ask one more question. if i want to random string and when i press button to stop it. I want the text slowly to stop same lottory

Comment: boolean flag = true;

while(flag) {
// do your thread work here
}

flag = false; //when you need to stop the thread

And I didn't understand your second question at all.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use some flag, which will determine when to setRandom when not
initilize boolean variable

```
boolean showRandom = false;
```

on button click set its value as follows

something like the folowing

```
 @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //          tv.setHint(tv.getHint());
    //          while(counter<2){
                showRandom = !showRandom;
                System.out.println("..show random.."+showRandom);
                t = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
    //                  register();
                        try {
                            while(showRandom){
                                System.out.println("..print dialog..");
   sleep(1000);
handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());


    //                        }
                            }

                }catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                    }
                };
                t.start();

                }

    //      }
        });
```

Comment: I want to ask one more question. if i want to random string and when i press button to stop it. I want the text slowly to stop same lottory. How can i do it

Comment: hmm i will test tomorrow because I don have sumsung galaxy for test it now

Comment: how can i random by slow text when press button second time for stop it

Comment: why when double click on button the program will Hold.